# at least one in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a database related to movies. This is how I inserted my data in the database:

```
db.Movieinfo.insert({ 
    "MovieID":1,
    "MovieName":"iron man",
    "Actor":"Robert downey",
    "ReleaseDate":2008,
    "GotOscars":1,      
})
```

But when I do the following to get the list of movies which returns only movies that have won at least one oscar or more: 
`db.Movieinfo.find({"MovieName":1},{"GotOscars":{$gte:1}})`, it gives all the movies that haven't won oscar also. Could anyone please help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: db.Movieinfo.find({ "GotOscars":{$gte:1} })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongoDB search query uses: `db.collection.find(<query>, <projection>)`

To find the names of all movies with more or equal to one oscar use:

```
db.Movieinfo.find({"GotOscars":{$gte:1}}, {"MovieName":1});
```

To find full movie details of movies with more or equal to one oscar use:

```
db.Movieinfo.find({"GotOscars":{$gte:1}})
```

You can learn more about in the official documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
db.Movieinfo.find({"GotOscars":{$gte:1}})
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/
you were passing 2 arguments and another argument was considered as projection.